# How do I check the stability of a discrete transfer function?

Tags: control-system

[image]

[image]

I calculated the transfer function and let n = 1 , but how do I check the stability of the discrete time system when n = 1?

Comment: BIBO stability?

Answer (score 2):

\$e^{-ns}\$ transforms to \$z^{-n}\$. Then check the magnitudes of the poles; they all need to be within the unit circle.